# Extracting USPTO Family Id for Patents

Tags: uspto, bulk-download, family, family-id

Is there any bulk data source where we can extract the "Family ID" for each patent?

The "Family ID" data is shown in the search app from USPTO (http://patft.uspto.gov).

I looked into USPTO Bulk data but cound not find it there (https://bulkdata.uspto.gov/).

Patent Grant Full Text Data (No Images) (JAN 1976 - PRESENT)
Contains the full text of each patent grant issued weekly (Tuesdays) from January 1, 1976 to present (excludes images/drawings). Subset of the Patent Grant Full Text Data with Embedded TIFF Images.

"Patent Family ID Number- The USPTO has recently begun assigning a patent family id number to correlate related documents under a unique Family ID number. Members of the family include published patent applications, US patents, and foreign references, as well as other documents. The information has been added retroactively to the PatFT database, so it is available back to 1970."
src: http://ptrca.org/newsletters/2016/comfort

Answer (score 0):

PatentsView allows bulk download
http://www.patentsview.org/web/

You'll need to write a regular expression to extract the Family ID from the XML file